# Understanding Polynomial Regression Equation with multiple Independent Variable

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Understanding Polynomial Regression.
I understand that we use polynomial regression for some kind of non Linear Data set and to give it a curve. I know the equation of writing a Polynomial Regression for single independent variable but i don't really understand how this equation is constructed for 2 variables?

```
y = a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x1*x2 + a4 * x1^2 + a5 * x2^2
```

What will be the equation for Polynomial Regression in case we have 3 or more variables? What actually is the logic behind developing these polynomial equation for more than one variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose whatever you want, but the general 'formula' (to the best of my own experience and knowledge) is:

- Powers (so `x1`, `x1^2`, `x1^3` etc) up to whichever number you choose (many stop at 2).
- Cross products (`x1 * x2`, `x1 * x3` etc)
- Combinations (`x1^2 * x2`, `x1 * x2^2` etc) and then you can even add higher combinations (`x1 * x2 * x3`, and you can even add powers here).

But this gets quickly out of hand, and you can end up with too many features.

I would stick to powers of 2, and cross products (only pairs) with no powers, quite like your example, and if you have three elements, then the multiplication of all three of them, but if you have more than three, I wouldn't bother with triplets.

The idea with polynomials is that you model the complex relationship between the features and polynomials are sometimes a good approximation to more complex relationships (that are not really polynomial in their nature).

I hope this is what you meant and that this can help you.